# Authoritative Server for single player but with leaderboard

Tags: unity, server

I made a Fps single player, timed survival with a leaderboard ( a bit like devil daggers and others).
I know would like to create a server that will prevent cheats such as avoiding collision or altering the timer.

My issue is I don't know the theory on how should my server behave. Should it run an instance of the game per player which will handle the collision and other stuff for that player ? is this viable

Any advice ?

Comment: I will try the mmo 'zone' stuff, this should allow me to run on instance of the game for many user and prevent them from interacting one with another.
May not be the best solution but it should do it for the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent cheating then the client could be treated as a dummy terminal displaying state and accepting input. The problem with this is that you have offloaded ALL of the work to your server. As the number of people increases on the server so to will the computational load.

Correcting this problem can be solved in a number of ways such as multiple server processes sharing the work or load balancing. Another solution can be to offload more expensive computations to other processes.

Another solution is to store the player data and run cheat computations in parallel or when computational load is reduced to detect if any player actions violate game rules.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring an always-on connection to a remote server and handling all mechanics on that server is not really justifiable for a single-player game.

But what you could do instead is add a replay-feature for your game. Have the game log all player input to a file. Then add a mode where the game plays itself automatically by using the log of a previous game as input. When your game uses randomness, also store the RNG seed in the replay so the game can exactly reproduce all random events.

When a player uploads a high-score, have them also upload the replay log. That way people can not just look at the names and scores of other players, but can also download the replay and see for themselves *how* the other player did it. When that player is grossly cheating, everyone can see it and report it. You could even have the server determine the score by itself by doing a replay and checking the score.

When you discover a hack for your game, you can also automatically check older replays for evidence that this hack was used and delete them retroactively.